# How to override GET arguments approach in BackboneJS on fetch?

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, express

I have the following Collection:

```
var collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
   url: '/documents/'
});
```

When I do fetch, I need ro pass additional agrument to my query. When I do the following:

```
var collection.fetch({
    data: {
       key: 2
    }
});
```

Issied request is:

```
GET: /documents/?key=2;
```

But I need to use expressjs approach to my query will:

```
GET: /documents/key/2
```

How could I make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override collection's fetch method

```
var collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
     fetch: function(options) {
          if (options.data) {
               options.url = '/documents/key/' + options.data.key;
               delete options.data;
          }
          Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch.call(this, options);
     }
});
```

Here, we just manually set url everytime we do a `fetch`, and delete that `data` property in case the `$.ajax` behind the scene takes it to construct a url with question marks.

Internally, Backbone.sync() is what happens when we call fetch(), save(), and destroy() on models, and fetch() and create() on collections.

You can see the source http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-141 here:

```
if (!options.url) {
  params.url = _.result(model, 'url') || urlError();
}
```

So instead of using the `url` on model (which is set dependently on the model's collection, you can see the `url` on model in source too), we explicitly set the url ourselves.

And in the end:

```
    var xhr = options.xhr = Backbone.ajax(_.extend(params, options));
```

As you can see, now `$.ajax` uses `options.url` instead.

Answer (score 0):

url parameter can be a function. You can change url in this function.

**Example**

```
   url: function () {
        var u = '/documents/';
        if (this.key){
          u += '/key/' + this.key
        }
        return u; 
   }
```

for more information you can see this post http://japhr.blogspot.com/2011/10/overriding-url-and-fetch-in-backbonejs.html